# Update a line in an invoice in open-source QuickBooks PHP DevKit on GitHub

Tags: quickbooks

I am using the open-source QuickBooks PHP DevKit on GitHub. Suppose their are three line items in a invoice. Is it possilbe to update third line item? Also Is it possible to delete an invoice? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the example of updating an invoice here:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_invoice_update.php

You'll first retrieve the invoice from QuickBooks:

```
$invoices = $InvoiceService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE Id = '34' ");
$Invoice = $invoices[0];
```

Then you can get the third line item:

```
$Line = $Invoice->getLine(2);   // zero-indexed, so "2" is the third line item
```

Then you can change it:

```
$Line->setDescription('Here is my updated description');
```

Then update the invoice:

```
$resp = $InvoiceService->update($Context, $realm, $Invoice->getId(), $Invoice);
```

Comment: Thanks. updation by line worked. Is it possible to delete an invoice?

Comment: @Shino Example of deleting an invoice https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_invoice_delete.php